# Checking that code is set on url parameter with link

Tags: php, wordpress

What's the best method to check that `$_GET['code']` exists on a particular admin link?

This is what I currently have:

```php
if (isset($_GET['code'])
```

How can I make it as this?

```php
if (isset(admin_url('options-general.php?page=instagram_auth')))
```

then grab the `$_GET['code']`?

Comment: Do you want to check the filename and the page parameter then grab the code parameter?

Comment: It's very hard to understand what you mean. You say have if (isset($_GET['code']) and then you ask how to grab the $_GET['code']? What has that to do with admin_url?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the values of $_SERVER, if you want to check any part of the request url.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php